# multiply and add values in json format from http response

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I make calls to an API which returns the data as needed with the below code

```
search() {
    this.apiService.getResults()
    .subscribe(
      response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.data = response.data
        }
      },
      err => {
      }
    );

  }
```

The structure of the response looks like this

```
this.data = [{name:Corn Flakes, price: 40, quantity: 20, name: 'Oats', price: 32, quantity: 23, name: 'Springles', price: 3, quantity: 88}]
```

View

```
    <tr *ngFor="let item of searchResults; let i = index"
                class="table-row" #row>
              <td>
                {{i + 1}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{item.name}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{item.price}}
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{item.quantity}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{item.price * item.quantity | currency:'GHc ':'code'}}
              </td>
            </tr>

Overall Total =
```

I'm able to compute against each row to know the subtotal.
What I want to achieve in the view is to compute the price and quantity to know the sum of all the items put together

Comment: And what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component, when the async call is resolved you can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to accumulate the total like below and then add a new field `total` to the component class to display in the view.

```js
const data = [{name:'Corn Flakes', price: 40, quantity: 20, name: 'Oats', price: 32, quantity: 23, name: 'Springles', price: 3, quantity: 88}];

const total = data.reduce((sum, {price, quantity}) => sum += price * quantity, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Component code:

```
class YourComponent{
   public total: number; 
}
```

Template:

```
Overall Total = {{total}}
```